# Android NameValuePair not Accepting String

Tags: android, http-post

I am using HTTPPost to send values to a server.  The script works fine with what I have below.  However if I change the name value pair to this I get a force close:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", idOfTextView.getText().toString()));
```

This is the code without it reading the textview:

```
 String url_select = "http://mydomain.com/get.php";
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        //read content
        is =  httpEntity.getContent();                  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();               
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    return null;
```

Comment: What's the error in logcat? Also, make sure `idOfTextView` is non-null.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException > 06-14 15:27:36.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29275): at com.sample.sampleapp.viewRandom$task.doInBackground(viewRandom.java:78)
Line 78 would be the line where I am trying to set the namevaluepairs.

Comment: Then either idOfTextView is null, or idOfTextView.getText() is null, according to your error log

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction. I had to define idOfTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView); inside my oncreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my comment was the answer, make sure `idOfTextView` is non-null.

Comment: Yes it was... I was going to ask you to post so I could give you credit for it. Lol.